# Duplicate questions indicator plural syntax

Tags: bug

I asked a question that had been asked previously...
My question is here: [How to set a SELECT control using text instead of value using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540844/how-to-set-a-select-control-using-text-instead-of-value-using-jquery/28540952#28540952)

And it was marked as [duplicate] by a moderator, with 2 similar questions..

But the site displays the wrong syntax. It says:

```
This question already has an answer here:
                          ---------
```

When it should really say:

```
This question already has answers here:
                          ^^^^^^^
```

Especially since there are more than one questions with similar context.

[image]

Comment: For the person who down-voted, please indicate the reason

Comment: [Wait for a giant S with your name on it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/168149)

Comment: No moderator was involved. Gold badge is not a diamond.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really too minor, plus not really a problem.

"This question already has an answer here" can be interpreted as "There is at least one answer among those listed below that answers this question as well" - and that answer is what you seek.

Comment: So I can stop typing now then..! If there's more than one answer there's still "an" answer, there's just some others as well.